# Using Time.timeScale to pause causes my player to 'dash' when unpausing, how do I stop this?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm moving my player with Input.GetAxis() and AddForce().

When I unpause the game with Time.timeScale = 1f, the player dashes forward at a higher speed (past my speed limit) even with the movement keys unpressed.

How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for restricting speed from exceeding max limit you can use 'normalized'

```
void FixedUpdate()
{          
  if(rigidbody.velocity.magnitude > maxSpeed){
       rigidbody.velocity = rigidbody.velocity.normalized * maxSpeed;
   }

}
```

also you can use Vector3.ClampMagnitude. 
see this https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.ClampMagnitude.html
to be more specific you can share the part of the script.

Comment: fixed the issue. I had a version of the .normalized line, only, it was in Update() instead of FixedUpdate().

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the force is still being applied and added constantly while the game is paused.

You could record the amount of force being applied to the player right before you set Time.timeScale = 0 and when you set Time.timeScale = 1f you could set the force to the recorded force before you paused.